# Passing id of button to jquery post method

Tags: jquery, vb.net

I am trying to pass the `ID` of the `asp.net` button that I am clicking on at that time I am trying the following but compiler does not seem to like it sorry my `jquery` is a bit rusty, this is my code :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function AddToFavourites() {
        var element = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/AddToFavourites",
            data: '{productId:'+ element.attr('id') + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
 </script>
```

It is this line here that it is failing on  :

> data: '{productId:'+ element.attr('id') + "}",

Also is their a way right after this call get return the result to change the fa-heart icon to red once I have checked the db that the person has favored the product.

**Edit 3**

To Show the output of console .log

```
VM41:1 POST http://localhost:52448/dynamic/Favourite.aspx/AddToFavourites 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ VM41:1
send @ jquery.js:9664
ajax @ jquery.js:9215
AddToFavourites @ Aspen:24
onclick @ Aspen:919
```

Quite strange as I have the function in my code behind on that file

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function AddToFavourites(productId As String) As String
Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStr").ConnectionString
     Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Dim strQuery As String
        'set up the sql command
        Dim oSqlCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        '   oSqlCommand.Connection = oSqlConn

        Dim oDataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
        Dim oLinesTable As New DataTable

        Dim strProductID As String
        strProductID = productId.Replace("product_", "")

     End Using

    Return ""

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your line `data: '{productId:'+ element.attr('id') + "}",`

with:

```
data: {'productId': element.attr('id') },
```